# Retain count when loading UITableViewCell with loadNibNamed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsbundle

I am using `loadNibNamed:owner:options:` as documented by [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20) to load a custom UITableViewCell from a nib file:

```
ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
if (cell == nil) {
    // (1)
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ItemCell" owner:self options:nil];
    // (2)
    cell = self.itemCell;
    self.itemCell = nil;
    // (3)
    // code continues here
}
```

And the class declaration of the view controller:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
@private
    UITableView *tableView;
    ItemCell *itemCell;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ItemCell *itemCell;
```

MyViewController is the File's Owner of the ItemCell.

I am observing the following:

- (1) `self.itemCell` retain count is 0
- (2) `self.itemCell` retain count is 2
- (3) `self.itemCell` retain count is 0
- (3) `cell` retain count is 1

Could someone explain:

- **Why does `self.itemCell` retain count go from 2 to 0 between (2) and (3)?**
- **Why is the retain count of `cell` in (3) equal to 1?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## retainCount is useless.  Don't call it.

As for the answer to your two questions, "implementation detail".

As long as you balance your retains and releases, your job is done.   Explaining why the retain count is any given absolute value would require access to the implementation of the frameworks themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, made a mistake, in (3)

In (3) I was calling `[self.itemCell retainCount]` to view the retain count but since `self.itemCell` was set to `nil` already , all I was getting was 0 obviously!! Not sure how I missed that...

in (3), `cell` retain count is 1 which is normal (the cell is retained by the array returned by `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`)